# Index Item Alterer

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone help me out here?

I'm trying to create a small javascript code snippet that selects a random item from and array and alters it to be either 'A', 'T', 'G' or 'C' (dna strands) but it cannot be what it was.

Thanks a million.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, [not a painting of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1048572)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pick random element in an array AVOIDING (EXCEPT if it's) a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811267/how-to-pick-random-element-in-an-array-avoiding-except-if-its-a-certain-value)

Comment: What if you generate three values? is 'A' 'T' 'A' possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get random elements from `[A, T, G, C]`, not just from `dnaStr`, because `dnaStr` does not have equal amount of each items, for example there is 3 T and 5 G

Here's the function that gives 1 or many random items from array

```js
const numbers = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']

function randomTimes(arr, times = 1) {
  function randomItem() {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    return arr[index]
  }
  return Array.from({
    length: times
  }, randomItem).join('')
}

console.log('Single: ', randomTimes(numbers))

console.log('7: ', randomTimes(numbers, 7))
```